# React handleSubmit (with axios.post) with e.preventDefault still refreshes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First or all.. i'm very, very new to React and either though i have googled through a lot of posts regarding exactly this.. i have still yet not found out why my page refreshes.. anyone care to take a look ?

I have also tried e.stopPropagation() and e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation() without success..

Let me know if you need additional information:

**Registration.JS**

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
//import logo from './logo.svg';
import '../App.css';

const isValidPostalCode = value => /^\d{4}$/.test(value)
const isValidEmail = value => /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(value)
const isValidPhone = value => /^\[0-9]{8}$/.test(value)

class Registration extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      formData: {
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        email: "",
        phone: "",
        postalCode: "",
      },
      formErrors: {
        firstName: null,
        lastName: null,
        email: null,
        phone: null,
        postalCode: null,
      }
    }
  }

  onFirstNameChange(e) {
    console.log("FN = ", e.target.value)
    this.setState({
      formData: {
        ...this.state.formData,
        firstName: e.target.value
      },
    })
  }
  onLastNameChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      formData: {
        ...this.state.formData,
        lastName: e.target.value
      },
    })
  }
  onEmailChange(e) {
    const {
      value
    } = e.target

    this.setState({
      formData: {
        ...this.state.formData,
        email: value,
      },
      formErrors: {
        ...this.state.formErrors,
        email: isValidEmail(value) ? null : "Legg inn gyldig epost",
      }
    })
  }
  onPhoneChange(e) {
    const {
      value
    } = e.target

    this.setState({
      formData: {
        ...this.state.formData,
        phone: e.target.value
      },
      formErrors: {
        ...this.state.formErrors,
        phone: isValidPhone(value) ? null : "Telefonnummeret må være 8 tall",
      }
    })
  }
  onPostalCodeChange(e) {
    const {
      value
    } = e.target

    this.setState({
      formData: {
        ...this.state.formData,
        postalCode: e.target.value
      },
      formErrors: {
        ...this.state.formErrors,
        postalCode: isValidPostalCode(value) ? null : "Postnummer må være 4 tall",
      }
    })
  }
  render() {
    console.log("logging props in registration", this.props)
    return ( <
      form onSubmit = {
        (e) => {
          this.props.handleSubmit(e, this.state.formData.firstName, this.state.formData.lastName, this.state.formData.email, this.state.formData.phone, this.state.formData.postalCode)
        }
      } >
      <
      div className = "page-content" >
      <
      h3 > Registrering < /h3>

      <
      span > {
        this.props.trumfData.registrationintro
      } <
      /span>

      <
      span className = "registration-block" >
      <
      div className = "registration-block-line" >
      <
      input type = "text"
      placeholder = "Fornavn"
      onChange = {
        (e) => this.onFirstNameChange(e)
      }
      value = {
        this.props.trumfData.firstname ? this.props.trumfData.firstname : this.state.formData.firstName
      }
      /> <
      input type = "text"
      placeholder = "Etternavn"
      onChange = {
        (e) => this.onLastNameChange(e)
      }
      value = {
        this.state.formData.lastName
      }
      /> <
      /div> <
      div className = "registration-block-line" >
      <
      input type = "text"
      placeholder = "Epost"
      onChange = {
        (e) => this.onEmailChange(e)
      }
      value = {
        this.state.formData.email
      }
      /> {
        this.state.formErrors.email
      } <
      /div> <
      div className = "registration-block-line" >
      <
      input type = "text"
      placeholder = "Telefon"
      onChange = {
        (e) => this.onPhoneChange(e)
      }
      value = {
        this.state.formData.phone
      }
      /> {
        this.state.formErrors.phone
      } <
      input type = "text"
      placeholder = "Postnr"
      onChange = {
        (e) => this.onPostalCodeChange(e)
      }
      value = {
        this.state.formData.postalCode
      }
      /> <
      /div> <
      /span> {
        " "
      } {
        this.props.trumfData.isauthenticatd && < input type = "checkbox" > Kryss av... < /input>
      } <
      input type = "submit"
      value = "Registrer din stemme" / >

      <
      /div> <
      /form>
    );
  }
}

export default Registration;
```

**APP.JS**

```js
handleSubmit(e, firstName, lastName, email, phone, postalCode) {
  alert('Submitted: ' + firstName + ", " + lastName);
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
  this.setState({
    step: 3,
    ...this.state.userVote,
    FirstName: firstName,
    LastName: lastName,
    Email: email,
    MobileNumber: phone,
    ZipCode: postalCode
  })
  axios.post('http://localhost:54467/api/poll/vote', this.state.userVote)
    .then(response => {
      console.log("VI HAR SENDT INN !!!:", response.data)
      // this.setState({ trumfdata: response.data })
    })
    .catch(err => console.log("Error", err))
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding e.preventDefault() to the function you added to the onSubmit property? `form onSubmit = {
        (e) => { // add e.preventDefault() here
          this.props.handleSubmit(e, this.state.formData.firstName, this.state.formData.lastName, this.state.formData.email, this.state.formData.phone, this.state.formData.postalCode)
        }
      } >`

Comment: @MichaelSorensen : will try riiight away.. i'll come back to you..

Comment: That actually solved it :) thanx @MichaelSorensen... Have no idea why i had to do that though.. 

You might want to answer this, so i can mark it as accepted ?

Comment: Awesome, I'll right up a concise answer in case someone else happens to stumble upon this thread :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** Add e.preventDefault() to the form's onSubmit property

```
form onSubmit = {
    (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.props.handleSubmit(e, this.state.formData.firstName, this.state.formData.lastName, this.state.formData.email, this.state.formData.phone, this.state.formData.postalCode)
    }
  } >
```

<s>**But Why though?** preventDefault() simply needs to be the first thing that you do otherwise you run the risk of of whatever event you are trying to prevent running before you have a chance to stop it. I made a codepen to illustrate what I mean: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/odfgavb</s>

[Edit] The previous answer I provided was wrong. It's possible that the true issue lies within passing the function down as a prop. I can't be sure. If anyone does know why please post the answer here.